# Resistor 100k¾ indicated in datasheet

Tags: resistors, datasheet, component-values

I was reading the datasheet of a digital multimeter (DMM) and I came across a resistance value terminated with 3/4, like so:

[image]

You can find it at the bottom of page 1-3 of the [this](https://download.tek.com/manual/2000-903-01--C-Oct2007--QSG.pdf#page=14) document.

What does it mean?

Comment: Ω2 and Ω4 refer to 2-wire and 4-wire resistance measurement techniques, respectively, while 100kΩ is just a resistance value.

Comment: Oh boy, mojibake strikes again...

Comment: Same substitution appears throughout the document, not just page 1-3.

Comment: @TobySpeight https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake (in short: character encoding messed-up during decoding/typesetting). Just for the people that didn't know the term since now (as I did) :-)

Comment: I knew Hogwarts wizards had a lightning spell, but didn't know they went as far as publishing some DMM datasheets :)

Answer (score 26):

That's just a "typo" caused by an incorrect encoding specified for the characters/text of the datasheet, or the wrong font; something went wrong with the typesetting.

Just read "Ω" where it says "¾".